# Android i get NULL when i post data with Retrofit

Tags: android

I'm novice on using `Retrofit`, I want to post data as an `json` data with `object` format to server and get response from that, I tested my restful url with fake data and that work fine without any problem, but when i post data from android i get `null`. what i want to do? i want to post data to server and get response with this format:

```
public class UserLoginInformation {
    private String username;
    private String userUniqueId;
}
```

My `interface`:

```
public interface SignalRetrofitServiceProviders {
    @POST("joinUserToApplication")
    Call<List<UserLoginInformation>> joinUserToApplication(@Body Object data);
}
```

post data:

```
private void joinUserToApplication(String data) {
    AlachiqRestFullProvider  signalProvider  = new AlachiqRestFullProvider();
    SignalRetrofitServiceProviders signalRetrofitServiceProviders = signalProvider.getServices();

    Call<List<UserLoginInformation>> call = signalRetrofitServiceProviders.joinUserToApplication(data);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<UserLoginInformation>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<UserLoginInformation>> call, Response<List<UserLoginInformation>> response) {
            List<UserLoginInformation> result = response.body();
            final String               r      = new Gson().toJson(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<UserLoginInformation>> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("onFailure ", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

RestFull provider:

```
public class AlachiqRestFullProvider {
    private SignalRetrofitServiceProviders signalRetrofitServiceProviders;

    public AlachiqRestFullProvider() {
        OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ClientSettings.ALACHIQ_WEB_BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        signalRetrofitServiceProviders = retrofit.create(SignalRetrofitServiceProviders.class);
    }

    public SignalRetrofitServiceProviders getServices() {
        return signalRetrofitServiceProviders;
    }
}
```

data for post:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("mobileNumber", mobileNumber);
        jsonObject.put("userUniqueId", uuid);
        jsonObject.put("userPhoneNumbers", phoneContacts);

        startService(
                new Intent(context, AlachiqRestFullWebServiceProvider.class)
                        .putExtra("request_type", "joinUserToApplication")
                        .putExtra("data", jsonObject.toString()));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

server response data like with this format:

```
{"username":"mahdi","userUniqueId":"fwcrwcrwr23234c24"}
```

server side application to get data is:

```
Route.post('joinUserToApplication', function *(request, response) {
    console.log(request._raw);
    response.send({username: "mahdi", userUniqueId: "fwcrwcrwr23234c24"});
});
```

Comment: You are posting a Object as your body. Construct the actual POJO and serialize that and send it

Comment: @gaara87 how can i serialize that?

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration use any of these to help with the serialization and deserialization

Comment: @gaara87 i used that, my post updated

Comment: awright, i'll post that as the answer then, please do accept it when you get the chance

Answer (score 0):

The POST body that is being serialized is a generic Object.

Create a POJO with the fields that you require and use a deserializer that retrofit understands

```
public interface SignalRetrofitServiceProviders {
    @POST("joinUserToApplication")
    Call<List<UserLoginInformation>> joinUserToApplication(@Body UserLoginInformation data);
}
```

Please note the parameter of the function is not changed to `UserLoginInformation`
http://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration

Comment: updated. I think we should take this offline into a chat if you need more help

Comment: doesn't seem to be working, i guess you can jus try my above snippet